# mpdf 504 gateway timeout error

Tags: pdf, gateway

i am using mpdf library in my project for report generation, when ever i generate report with minimum record it works fine but if there is more record of more than 2000 and i want to generate the pdf report for that record it's give error **Gateway Timeout**. i search for the issue on internet i fount solution of different developer who face issue of gate way time out. i increase the php **memory_limit=1024M** and set execution time = 600 but still have error. Please any one help thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Wtu.png)

Answer (score 1):

"504 - Gateway Timeout Error" simply means Server is not responsive. A server is taking too much time to respond. The server may be down. I don't see any other issue. 
and look her to fix this issue
https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/